# Progress bar in wix behaves differently while uninstalling

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.8

I have create a progress bar for my bootstrapper installer. It goes correctly upto 100% while installing. But while uninstalling it only goes to 50% and stops there. Below is my code.

In the constructor of my ViewModel class.

```
this.Bootstrapper.CacheAcquireProgress += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.cacheProgress = args.OverallPercentage;
                this.Progress = (this.cacheProgress + this.executeProgress) / 2;
            };
            this.Bootstrapper.ExecuteProgress += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.executeProgress = args.OverallPercentage;
                this.Progress = (this.cacheProgress + this.executeProgress) / 2;
            };
```

Then getter and setter as follows.

```
  private int progress;
        public int Progress
        {
            get { return progress; }
            set
            {
                this.progress = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Progress");
            }
        }

        private int cacheProgress;
        private int executeProgress;
```

what am I doing wrong here? Why does the bar stay at 50% while uninstalling, though the uninstall is complete? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every Apply action will have a Cache phase, use the `OnApplyPhaseCount` (in v4 it's in the `OnApplyBegin`) callback to know what that denominator should be.

Comment: I couldn't find any examples on how to do this using OnApplyPhaseCount. Could you please provide me with an example?